# Is there a way to name a range within excel using xlwings API? Trying to use string formulas that reference excel defined ranges

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to use xlwing's sheetname.range("Some object defined range").formula = "=Some excel formula" function, but I am not sure about how I can reference an object defined range as a string within the formula above.

I was able to define the object range as follows:

```
X = sht0.range('C10').expand('down').value
```

For all values within this range, I would like to perform a calcuation using an excel formula and I would like to use the following function.

```
sht0.range('F1').formula = "=SUM(X)"
```

It's a simple Sum function that could work if I just use the sum(X) function in python and use the result in the equation above without creating a string, but what if I would like to use any other built in excel functions instead?

One potential work around is using the xw.api syntax to create a "Named Range" in excel using the pywin32 syntax, but I can't seem to figure out what the syntax conversion would be.

As an example, in VBA it's:

```
Range("D7").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SomeNameforaRange", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R7C4"
```

I tried the following in xlwings for python along with a few other attempts in the syntax:

```
sht0.range('C10').expand('down').api.Names = "SomeNameforaRange"
```

...but that doesn't work. It would just freeze my notebook or gives me an error.

Sorry if this question is very basic, I am a bit new to Python and xlwings, but I appreciate any help you may be to give.

Comment: Named ranges are fully supported via xlwings, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#names. E.g. `sht0.range('C10').expand('down').name = "SomeNameforaRange"`

Comment: Using this works! Thank you for the prompt response!